Why can't DynamoDB deserialize IList<T> in .NET?
I previously had properties of type List<T> and this worked fine with DynamoDB. However, according to CA1002, we should not expose generic lists, so I changed to using IList<T>. This is causing a problem with DynamoDB, particularly during deserialization. Serialization seems fine as I can see L – List data type descriptor in each row.
Why is IList<T> treated differently during deserialization?

Unable to convert DynamoDB entry
[Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.DynamoDBList] of type
Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.DynamoDBList to property MyModel
of type System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[MyApp.Models.MyModel,
MyApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]


Maybe because IList is just an interface and the deserialization cannot create an instance of an interface, because you need a (non-abstract) class to create an instance

Excellent example of why you shouldn't always change your code to please a tool.
